# Filtering rows if two columns values are not same - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to apply date filter on rows where OwningOfficeID and ScopeOfficeID is not same.

Here is the main query;

```
SELECT distinct v.VisitID, a.OfficeID AS OwningOfficeID, 
       scp.OfficeID AS ScopeOfficeID, V.VisitDate, 
       a.staffID as OwningStaff ,scp.StaffID as OwningScope
 FROM Visits v 
    INNER JOIN VisitDocs  vdoc ON vdoc.VisitID = v.VisitID 
    INNER JOIN InspectionScope scp ON scp.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
    INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = scp.AssignmentID 
    INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.StaffID = a.StaffID
 WHERE 
  v.VisitType = 1  AND
 --'SCOPE OWNER AND LOOK FOR INSPECTION REPORT BUT NOT FOR COORD/FINAL REPORT.
     (scp.StaffID = 141
        AND EXISTS(SELECT *           
                     FROM VisitDocs d          
                    WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID          
                      AND d.docType = 13)          
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                         FROM VisitDocs d  
                        WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID  AND d.docType IN (1,2))
     )
     OR 
--'ASSIGNMENT OWNER AND NOT SCOPE OWNER AND LOOK FOR COORDINATOR REPORT. 
(a.StaffID = 141 AND scp.StaffID != 141
 AND EXISTS(SELECT *           
                 FROM VisitDocs d          
                 WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID          
                 AND d.docType = 2)          
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM VisitDocs d  
                 WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID  AND d.docType IN (1))
 )
```

Result Set

[image]

Following condition can be applied to outer select query to achieve the results.

(OwningOfficeID <> ScopeOfficeID  AND VisitDate >='01/11/2012' OR OwningOfficeID = ScopeOfficeID)

Is there anyway to do it in the one select statement?

Comment: Don't mix AND and OR without explicitly using parentheses.

Comment: You can write the condition more compactly as `((OwningOfficeID = ScopeOfficeID) OR (VisitDate >='01/11/2012'))`

Comment: i want to display all rows where OwningOfficeID = ScopeOfficeID OR OwningOfficeID <> ScopeOfficeID BUT also need to apply date filter on those rows where OwningOfficeID <> ScopeOfficeID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by one select statement, but I think what you really want to know is how to do this query so that it runs quickly, is easy to see it is correct and easy to maintain.

Here is how to do that; use CTEs.  (If you don't know what a CTE is go read about them and then come back here -- they are documented on Microsoft's website.)

CTEs can be much faster and clearer than sub-queries.  Let me show you how, taking the code above and re-factoring with CTEs I get:

```
WITH DocTypes AS 
(
   SELECT VisitID, docType
   FROM VisitDocs
), DocType13 AS
(
   SELECT VisitID
   FROM DocTypes 
   WHERE docType = 13
), DocType1and2 AS
(
   SELECT VisitID
   FROM DocTypes 
   WHERE docType IN (1,2)
), DocType1 AS
(
   SELECT VisitID
   FROM DocTypes1and2 
   WHERE docType = 1
), DocType2 AS
(
   SELECT VisitID
   FROM DocTypes1and2 
   WHERE docType = 2
), Base AS
(
  SELECT distinct v.VisitID, a.OfficeID AS OwningOfficeID, 
         scp.OfficeID AS ScopeOfficeID, V.VisitDate, 
         a.staffID as OwningStaff ,scp.StaffID as OwningScope
   FROM Visits v 
      INNER JOIN VisitDocs  vdoc ON vdoc.VisitID = v.VisitID 
      INNER JOIN InspectionScope scp ON scp.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
      INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = scp.AssignmentID 
      INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.StaffID = a.StaffID
   WHERE 
    v.VisitType = 1  AND
   --'SCOPE OWNER AND LOOK FOR INSPECTION REPORT BUT NOT FOR COORD/FINAL REPORT.
       (scp.StaffID = 141
          AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DocType13 d WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID)          
          AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DocType1and2 d WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID)
       )
       OR 
  --'ASSIGNMENT OWNER AND NOT SCOPE OWNER AND LOOK FOR COORDINATOR REPORT. 
  (a.StaffID = 141 AND scp.StaffID != 141
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DocType2 d WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID)          
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DocType1 d WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID)
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM Base
WHERE (OwningOfficeID <> ScopeOfficeID 
      AND VisitDate >='01/11/2012'( 
      OR OwningOfficeID = ScopeOfficeID
```

It should be clear why this is better, but if it isn't briefly:

- All the selects you see at the beginning are exactly as they were in the original query, but because they are broken out prior the optimizer has an easier time, it will do better than when they were sub-queries -- I've seen huge changes in some cases, but in any case the optimizer has the option now to do a better job of memory caching and such.
- It is clearer and easier to test.  If you have problems with the query you can test it easy, comment out the main select and just select one of the the sub-queries, is it what you expect?  These sub-queries are simple, but they can get complicated and this makes it easier.
- You said you wanted to apply some logic to this query. I've added it to the CTE, as you can see it makes this complicated "layering" simple.

Comment: Thanks for showing CTEs method. I have tried that and can't see much difference in the performance.

Comment: @user1263981 - performance has many factors - size of tables, indexes, etc - you don't always see magic -- but you do see how to add your additional conditions to this query now?

Comment: don't know how to fit (OwningOfficeID <> ScopeOfficeID AND VisitDate >='01/11/2012' OR OwningOfficeID = ScopeOfficeID) with cte

Comment: Ok @user1263981 I added that to may answer, it should be clear doing so was trivial now.  Please take a look at the difference edit to see how simple it was to add this seemingly complicated logic to the query chain.

Comment: CTE's are _exactly the same_ as subqueries, performance-wise. In fact, many times performance will degrade when using CTE's. Not because CTE's are different, but because the enhanced readability will tempt developers to write even more complex queries.

Comment: @SKoppenol - We disagree on this since I've seen queries where using a CTE will speed it up (esp if a sub-query is used more than once like above), of course any bad programmer can make mistakes with any tool and create something which does not perform well.